# LESS compile error on individual bootstrap components

Tags: node.js, twitter-bootstrap, less, server-side

I am a little bit confused.  I am trying to use Node.js with lessc to compile my application which includes parts of bootstrap.  I want to be able to pick bits and pieces of bootstrap for what I need since I won't be using all of it.  When I import `bootstrap.less` everything compiles perfectly.  But if I import just `reset.less` or `buttons.less` I get: `TypeError: Cannot call method 'charAt' of undefined`.  What is going on here?

**My Folder Setup**

```
less/
    application.less
    bootstrap/
        bootstrap.less
        reset.less
        buttons.less
        etc...
```

**application.less**

Everything compiles fine when I have `@import 'bootstrap/bootstrap'`
I get the above error when I have `@import 'bootstrap/reset'`

And I have tried adding .less to the end of the file name as well, same results.
I found online that less version 1.3.0 should fix this, but that is the version I am using.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The components are dependent on the `variables.less` and `mixins.less`. You will need to include them when compiling any component (or even just the `reset.less`, since it uses the mixins).